Manual image registration
I have two images. One is as seen by the [camera] and the other is a [simulation] (and hence has less details, though the resolution is same). I want to correct any translation and scaling between the images.
I tried common image registration methods based on cross-correlation, FFT, and optical flow, but none were good enough.
Now, I want to do it manually and interactively. By simply dragging one image over the other and then noting the required translation. And something similar for scaling. Is there any free software that can help me do this? My images are currently in numpy format.

is the "simulated" image just the simulation, or the simulation on top of the real picture? I'm asking because the bottom edge of the rock agrees while the top edge doesn't. that suggests the issue isn't just translation or any other 2D image space transform, but an error in the model. -- what's the point of trying to visually align two objects that have clear discrepancies between each other? I'd recommend figuring out in what ways the model differs from the real world.

Simulation is pure theoretical calculation, which cannot be better than what I have currently. The objective is to map every pixel in the actual image to a pixel in the simulation.

Please provide proper images that folk can work with, rather than "plots" of images with extraneous axes. Thank you.

can you explain why the bottom edge of the rock aligns perfectly but the top edge doesn't?

@ChristophRackwitz It has to do with illumination from the Sun. The limb is generally sharper than the terminator, here the illumination source is towards the bottom.
All I need is a software that can open one image over the other in different colors and shift them manually by dragging.

if you just need translation, any image editor with layers should be able to do that. -- I don't believe that "illumination" explains what I see. the entire surface of the rock shifts. there is something going on that hasn't been described yet.

You can do manual registration in Photoshop. Open both images, copy one and paste it onto the other. Set the "Blend Mode" of the top layer to "Difference" then press v for "Move" and use the arrow keys to move the top image till it goes black - when the difference is zero and the images are registered. Probably possible in GIMP with similar method.

@ChristophRackwitz I see what you mean! I am not sure about the cause of this issue. This can be due to an error in the camera position/orientation information. It is one of many such observations, and only a few of them have this problem, so probably it is not inherent to the model.

@MarkSetchell Photoshop is a good option. But I am looking for free software. Also I'm not sure if in Photoshop I can get the translation values (shifts in x and y axes) in the end.

opencv, ECC refinement

It's pretty easy to get the offsets in Photoshop - just turn on theinfo window and look at the x,y position of the mouse pointer. Or count 1px for each tap of the arrow keys and count 10px for each arrow +shift key for larger offsets. GIMP is free.
